# API call through wp_remote_post function not working without print_r

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I am calling API through wp_remote_post function. It is working properly, When i am calling print_r($response['body']); function after that function but i don't want to print any value on screen. Is it possible to run wp_remote_post function without print_r function.

Comment: Yes, it's possible

Comment: @Justinas - Can you please give me some reference code?

Comment: Please give your sample code.

Comment: @Justinas  This is my code                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          $response = wp_remote_get($url);
if ( is_array( $response ) ) {
  $header = $response['headers']; // array of http header lines
  $body = $response['body']; // use the content
}
print_r($response['body']);

Comment: Edit question and never add code to comment as it's unreadable